# Export of (large) Dataset lasts very long

Tags: performance-tuning, export, dataset

I have a [`Dataset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dataset.html) (non numerical data) which has a [`ByteCount`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ByteCount.html) of about 14GB, When I export it to disc (SSD) the resulting ".m" or ".dat" file (I tried both) has about 3GB and the export. Process lasts about seven minutes.

**Is there a way to speed up the export process?**

Comment: Without knowing more about the data you would like to export, it might be hard to tell...

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher: It is LARGE Dataset, I can provide it via Link, but the data is also public available (JSON Format) at: https://datenspende.algorithmwatch.org/data.html I´m doing resaerch in this project.

Comment: @mgamer what you should have done was to share the code you have used to import that public data.

Comment: In my experience, a list of associations is a lot faster than a Dataset. And you can Query[ ] it just as well.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Answer

It seems that [`DumpSave`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DumpSave.html) is the fastest, based on my test below.

*Albert Retey*  offers a very relevant comment to this answer, which I think deserves to be highlighted here:

> There is an important difference between
>   [`Export`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Export.html) and
>   [`DumpSave`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DumpSave.html):
>   while `Export` will write (just) the data to file so it can be
>   re-imported with
>   [`Import`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Import.html),
>   `DumpSave` will store the definition for the symbol (here `ds`) and
>   recreate that definition when the file is loaded with `Get`. It will
>   overwrite previous definitions for that symbol and when loading data
>   you will need to know which definition a file will restore. So I would
>   suggest to use `Export[_,_,"MX"]` despite the fact that it is a bit
>   slower due to the extra overhead of the export framework...

### Dummy data

```
ds = Dataset[
   Array[<|
      "Words" -> RandomWord["KnownWords", 100],
      "Country" -> RandomEntity["Country"],
      "Reals" -> RandomReal[{0, 1}, 10^6],
      "Integers" -> RandomInteger[{1, 10}, 10^6],
      "Image" -> RandomImage[1, {100, 100}, ColorSpace -> "RGB"]
      |> &, 20]];
```

Only 0.3 GB, can't be bothered with more.

```
UnitConvert[Quantity[N@ByteCount[ds], "Bytes"], "Gigabytes"]
(* Quantity[0.324982, "Gigabytes"] *)
```

### [`Put`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Put.html) performance

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 Put[ds, "ds.m"];
 UnitConvert[Quantity[N@FileByteCount["ds.m"], "Bytes"], "Gigabytes"]
 ]
(* {131.745, Quantity[0.5267, "Gigabytes"]} *)
```

### [`BinaryWrite`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BinaryWrite.html) [`BinarySerialize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BinarySerialize.html) performance

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 file = CreateFile["PerformanceGoalSize.bin"];
 ow = OpenWrite[file, BinaryFormat -> True];
 BinaryWrite[ow, BinarySerialize[ds, PerformanceGoal -> "Size"]];
 UnitConvert[Quantity[N@FileByteCount[Close[ow]], "Bytes"], 
  "Gigabytes"]
 ]
(* {15.4984, Quantity[0.169483, "Gigabytes"]} *)

AbsoluteTiming[
 file = CreateFile["PerformanceGoalSpeed.bin"];
 ow = OpenWrite[file, BinaryFormat -> True];
 BinaryWrite[ow, BinarySerialize[ds, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"]];
 UnitConvert[Quantity[N@FileByteCount[Close[ow]], "Bytes"], 
  "Gigabytes"]
 ]
(* {3.43482, Quantity[0.324826, "Gigabytes"]} *)
```

### [`Export`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Export.html) performance

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 Export["Export.mx", ds];
 UnitConvert[Quantity[N@FileByteCount["Export.mx"], "Bytes"], 
  "Gigabytes"]
 ]
(* {0.149372, Quantity[0.324832, "Gigabytes"]} *)
```

### [`DumpSave`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DumpSave.html) performance

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 DumpSave[File["DumpSave.mx"], ds];
 UnitConvert[Quantity[N@FileByteCount["DumpSave.mx"], "Bytes"], 
  "Gigabytes"]
 ]
(* {0.142341, Quantity[0.324832, "Gigabytes"]} *)
```

Comment: Thanks you for this valuable hint. Up to now I haven't used the BinaryWrite command and DumpSave. Now I´m going to do so :-)

Comment: Is Export["whatever.mx"] the same as DumpSave[File["whatever.mx"]]?

Comment: @MichaelStern `Export["Export.mx", ds] `seems to be around the same time that `DumpSave["DumpSave.mx", ds]`.

Comment: @MichaelStern: there is an important difference between `Export` and `DumpSave`: while `Export` will write (just) the data to file so it can be reimported with `Import`, `DumpSave` will store the definition for the symbol (here `ds`) and recreate that definition when the file is loaded with `Get`. It will overwrite previous definitions for that symbol and when loading data you will need to know which definition a file will restore. So I would suggest to use `Export[_,_,"MX"]` despite the fact that it is a bit slower due to the extra overhead of the export framework...

Comment: @AlbertRetey A very good point!

Comment: Another important thing to consider (from the `DumpSave` documentation): "Files written by DumpSave can only be read on the same type of computer system on which they were written." I believe most ppl here know this, however.